# Access outer class instance in bound service

Tags: java, android, service

In android bound service, the following snippets access to service instance using `Foo.this` but in reality if we try to do it in java it can't be possible. So how it works?

```
public class LocalService extends Service { 
  private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

  public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
        return LocalService.this;
    }
  }

  @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return mBinder; }

  // Other public methods below
  public void foo() {} // etc...
}

// The activity class
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  LocalService mService;
  boolean mBound = false;
  ....
  .....
  private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)   {

        LocalBinder binder = (LocalService.LocalBinder) service;
        /* See, using this we can get the instance of LocalService in android, but using the same approach in java we get the error. */
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
  };
}
```

As you can see in MyActivity class, we can get the instance of `LocalService` class using `getService()` method (and after than we can access its methods). But if we try to do that in java we get the error.

In short, how `binder.getService()` call works in android.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with Java. Service is part of Android and doesn't apply to Java at all.

Comment: I mean, if I want to get the instance of outer class using `Foo.this`, so this is possible in android, as you can see in above example. But using the same in java in not possible. Why?

Comment: It is, but for non-static inner classes only. Android uses Java and doesn't extend it there.

Comment: Could you maybe add the code, which is not working?